# A problem when creating the socket

Tags: android, sockets

I've a android app which try to connect to server. But there is a problem when I create a socket. the application hang when it try implement the following line:

```
Socket socket= null;
socket = new Socket("192.168.0.15", 6565);
```

note that I have added this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

also I used the debug but it hang when it reach to creating socket line and I've got this detail about the error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket is not connected id=829731319824
```

and I am sure that port is not bound.
I appreciate your time.

Comment: Are you testing this on a device or the emulator? If its on a device do you have a firewall setup, like DroidWall?

Comment: Did you tried socket.setSoTimeout() ?

Comment: I tried it on San Francisco phone.. anroid sys 2.1update

Comment: Can you ping 192.168.0.15 from the adb shell?  Unless that's another host on a wifi network or lan your device is on, you probably won't be able to.  Also see if you can connect to there using netcat on the pc or adb shell.

Comment: How I can add socket.setSoTimeout() to my code and why.... thank u

Answer (score 2):

Your connection probably cannot be established or is taking some time to be established.

Operations on java.net.Socket are blocking that's why your application appears to be hung. To avoid "hanging" the UI, you should probably try to establish the connection using another thread so your UI thread won't block and will remain responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your connection cannot be established and the problem lies not within your code but the network setup. To avoid your app to hang, make sure you catch the SocketTimeoutException to be able to show an error message to the user along with some buttons to, for instance, try again or cancel the connection.

Comment: Please I am a new in android .. How to do that?